# How to upgrade only one projects ruby interpreter with RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm, upgrade

I simply want to upgrade the ruby I'm using on one project from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3.  However, I still need 1.8.7 for another project that is not currently being upgraded.  How can I upgrade the ruby using RVM and keep the gemset in tact?

Would `rvm upgrade 1.9.3 1.8.7` be the way to do this?  Won't that migrate every project using 1.8.7 to 1.9.3?

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems the way to do this would be with `rvm install 1.9.3` and then migrating gems for my project like so:

```
rvm gemset copy 1.8.7-p352@journal 1.9.3@journal
```

I'm going to try it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM supports multiple Rubies at once in its sandbox, which is its reason for existence. As a result, it's not necessary to upgrade 1.8.7 to 1.9.3. You can use a separate Ruby version, and/or gemsets for projects, or different paths, depending on how you want to set things up.

While you *CAN* upgrade across 1.8.7 to 1.9.3, I'd recommend keeping 1.8.7 at its final release, and install a separate version of 1.9.3 at its final release (currently p392), allowing easy testing between the two for compatibility. Install Ruby v2.0.0 also, and, as updates to it come out, use RVM to upgrade those to the most recent, deleting older versions as you see fit.

I think your:

```
rvm gemset copy 1.8.7-p352@journal 1.9.3@journal
```

will work to tell RVM to install the same gems in 1.9.3, or you can easily install them from scratch using a process something like:

1. `rvm use 1.8.7`
2. `gem list | awk '{print $1}' > ./gem_list`
3. `rvm install 1.9.3`
4. `rvm use 1.9.3`
5. `xargs gem install < ./gem_list`

It's been a while since I've done that so I'm going from memory.

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing it the way I posted in my question just as you also suggested and everything works great.  I didn't want to simply upgrade 1.8.7, so installing 1.9.3 was perfect

Answer (score 1):

To the project add an `rvmrc` file. When you `cd` into the project directory rvm will know which version of ruby to load. Then just run `bundle install` to get the gems that are in your Gemfile.

To install the ruby version and create an `rvmrc` file do:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p194
$ cd your_project_dir/
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@yourgemset --create --rvmrc
$ bundle install
```